# Array-style access of non-arrays (true, false, null, etc)

Tags: php, arrays, php-7.4

So, this is how my array is structured:

```
$this->response = [
    'code' => null,
    'errors' => null,
    'data' => null,
];
```

When I try to check if there are any errors I'll do it like this at the moment:

```
if ($response['errors'] !== null) {
   // code here
}
```

This gives me a notice in PHP 7.4:

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /app/src/Form/Form.php on line XX
```

I understand whats going on ([backward compatibility changes](https://www.php.net/manual/de/migration74.incompatible.php#migration74.incompatible.core.non-array-access)). Is there another clean way to check against `null` in an array? The only working method I see is this:

```
 if (isset($response['errors']) && $response['errors'] !== null) {
     // code here
 }
```

But this doubles my if statement. Isn't there a cleaner way?

Comment: `$this->response` != `$response`. Are you *sure* your `$response` is actually an array…!?

Comment: As you can see at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b470d610e2d1a57a83218d92e8892c00dfa7217, this does not trigger any notice in PHP 7.4 - as far as I see, the error is only then triggered if `$response` is `null`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since PHP 7.4 special notice informs about access to array item of variable that itself is `null`:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Initialize any variable with `null` in PHP that that variable behaves like it is not set:

```php
$a = null;
var_dump(isset($a)); // bool(false)
```

When you "initialize" **array item** with `null` same things happens:

```php
$a['name'] = null;
var_dump(isset($a['name'])); // bool(false)
```

Carefully use this check:

```php
if ($response['errors'] !== null)
```

because when `$response['errors']` is `null` for `isset()` it behaves like undefined index. At same time `array_keys()` returns keys initialized with `null`. So, cleaner way is:

- never initialize array items with `null` except cases when you want to delete item.
- use `isset($a['name'])` for checking array item.

Comment: No, this is wrong. A variable which is set but holds the value `null` **is still set**. Even if `isset` disagrees because of its idiosyncratic check for `null`. You can `var_dump` the array and you’ll see that value. That check makes perfect sense. See http://kunststube.net/isset

Comment: @deceze You're right. Answer updated.

Comment: It’s still wrong. PHP does **not** warn when you try to access an array item that holds the value `null`. This should be trivial for you to test. That warning is for when you *try to treat a `null` value like an array!* — And that check still makes perfect logical sense.

Comment: *”special notice informs about access to array item with null value”* is still wrong. OP’s problem is that `$response` itself is `null`, not a value within it.